# How to use late binding for cross version compatibility in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've got this code in excel 2013 but it does not work in excel 2007. The main difference seems to be microsoft excel 12.0 object library in 2007 vs version 15.0 in excel 2013.

How would I go about making it compatible across all versions of excel? I've looked into what's called "late binding" but I'm not sure how to modify my code in this regard.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportHistoricalDataSheet()

    Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS = 13056
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

    Dim aBody, sPath

    ' Download Historical Data xls file via XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    'With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        '.SetOption 2, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
        .Open "GET", "http://www.housepriceindex.ca/Excel2.aspx?langue=EN&mail=abc%40abc.com"
        .Send
        ' Get binary response content
        aBody = .responseBody
        ' Retrieve filename from headers and concatenate full path
        sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Replace(Split(Split(.GetAllResponseHeaders, "filename=", 2)(1), vbCrLf, 2)(0), "/", "-")
    End With
    ' Save binary content to the xls file
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .Write aBody
        .SaveToFile sPath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
    ' Open saved workbook
    With Workbooks.Open(sPath, , True)
        ' Get 1st worksheet values to array
        aBody = .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
    ' Delete saved workbook file
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFile sPath, True
    ' Insert array to target worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(aBody, 1), UBound(aBody, 2)).Value = aBody

End Sub
```

Comment: all of your code already uses **Late Binding**, are you getting an error ? cool nick-name B.T.W :)

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you! :) I tried running it on excel 2007 and it doesn't work. It crashes at ".Send"

Comment: @ShaiRado the only difference i could find between the two versions of excel were the microsoft excel 12.0 object library in 2007 vs version 15.0 in excel 2013.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "MSXML", so I don't want to say stuff I have no clue about

Comment: Try it with early binding (add references in the IDE), then you'll get more information on the failure

Comment: @Absinthe how do I do that?

Comment: @RageAgainstheMachine here you go https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264402.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your code already uses *late binding* with all the `CreateObject(...` statements.

But the library versions between the two machines (one running Excel 2007, one running Excel 2013) could be returning different types. You can check this with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestXMLHTTPType()

    Dim objXhr As Object

    Set objXhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    'check what you got
    Debug.Print TypeName(objXhr)

    Set objXhr = Nothing

End Sub
```

Do you get a different output on the two machines? This information will allow you to code for methods and property statements that compatible between Excel versions.

Comment: @ Robin Mackenzie I tried running your code, nothing is happening...where is it supposed to print to?

Comment: In the immediate window of the VB editor. That's where all output from debug.print goes. You may need to activate that window pane.

Comment: You can substitude `Debug.Print TypeName(objXhr)` for `MsgBox TypeName(objXhr)` if you want to see the error in a pop-up message box.

Answer (score 2):

So, how late binding works is, you declare the type as Object when you **declare** it.

```
Dim oSomething as Object
```

When you instantiate the object, you use a specific interface (IDispatch) dedicated for this binding, that looks up the functions at run time. This is why its called late binding. You use CreateObject to instantiate the object.

```
Set oSomeThing = CreateObject("SomeObject")
```

Early binding looks in the type library upfront so already knows the types.

Early binding will fail a compilation if some function doesn't exist - since it knows all the functions upfront. Late binding will pass a compilation but fail when it runs.

Now,

1. I would use early binding where possible. Then compile to see if you
   get any errors.
2. I would then open the older versions of Excel to and compile again to see if you get any compilation errors there.
3. If you get no errors, which you shouldn't, you need to run the application in debug to find the exact line the failure occurs and take it from there.